# How to debug Storm Crawler parse filter

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

I've got a situation where the XPathFilter isn't parsing some links in a page - possibly because of malformed HTML.

I can see the links are parseable directly with JSoup. I was wondering if there was an easy way to (perhaps a test case/rig) determine what XPathFilter was seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DebugParseFilter](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/parse/filter/DebugParseFilter.java). It will dump a XML representation of the webpage and this might give you some insights into why you are not getting the content with XPath. To do so, add DebugParseFilter to your parsefilters.json file, like any other ParseFilter.

It could be malformed HTML or dynamic content.

Comment: Is there an easy way to run this outside of a topology, to avoid loads of noise and target a single target URL to parse?

Comment: Not really. You could write a dummy topology with a MemorySpout to do that. We could add a main method to the ParserBolt, like we do e.g. for testing the protocols. Contributions welcome as usual!